# Append new facial encoding to a pickle file

Tags: python, pickle, face-recognition

I just want to add new facial encoding to the pickle file. I've tried the following the method but it's not working.

creating of the pickle file

```
import face_recognition
import pickle

all_face_encodings = {}

img1 = face_recognition.load_image_file("ex.jpg")
all_face_encodings["ex"] = face_recognition.face_encodings(img1)[0]

img2 = face_recognition.load_image_file("ex2.jpg")
all_face_encodings["ex2"] = face_recognition.face_encodings(img2)[0]


with open('dataset_faces.dat', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(all_face_encodings, f)
```

Appending new data to the pickle file.

```
import pickle


img3 = face_recognition.load_image_file("ex3.jpg")
all_face_encodings["ex3"] = face_recognition.face_encodings(img3)[0]

with open('dataset_faces.dat', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(img3,f)
    pickle.dump(all_face_encodings["ex3"],f)
```

But It's not working. Is there a way to append it?

Answer (score 1):

I guess your steps should be:

1. Load old pickle-data to memory to <all_face_encodings> dictionary;
2. Add a new encodings to the dictionary.
3. Dump the whole dictionary to pickle file again.